# Reduce dot size or padding to fit all page indicators on screen with UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageControl` that has 22 pages, therefore 22 page indicator dots. In landscape on iPhone they're all visible with plenty of space on the left and right, but in portrait there's not enough horizontal space to display all of the dots (at least on iPhone 4 and 5), so two aren't visible and the outer two are cut in half.

I am looking for a way to reduce the size of the dots or reduce the amount of padding between the dots to ensure all dots fit on screen in portrait. How can that be accomplished?

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you have that many dots, I would seriously consider a different control.  But if you want to stick to UIPageControl, I would just scale it down to fit on screen, with something like:

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.7);
```

This scales it down to 70% of its initial size - I leave it to you to determine the best scale for your screen size/number of pages.

Comment: can you please suggest another control?

Comment: @HRaval Personally I would try customising UISegmentedControl with three segments displaying a left arrow, "Page X of Y", and a right arrow.

Comment: thnx for your help...actually i need scrolling functionality with paging as i have large number of pages fetching from server, for that i am using horizontal collectionview. Is it right choice?

Comment: @HRaval Sure, ... or `UIPageViewController`[see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller).

Comment: what about not using dots at all? you could just display an arrow to indicate that there are more elements

Comment: Update it for swift3       `pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)`

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3 version code:** based on pbasdf answer.

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really not use a UIPageControl for something that has 22 pages. 
How about trying something like a label that returns a number instead. Will make you app look a lot cleaner.

Although if you REALLY want to use the pageControl, pbasdf's answer is spot on. 
 *pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)* 
should do the trick.