# Aligning page control

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol, pagecontrol

I have so many images in my page control that indicator dots are out of screen. Is there a way to align page control to left so that the dot related to first page will be visible on screen?

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve

[image]

I tried

```
imagesPageControl.contentMode = .Left
imagesPageControl.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left
```

but without success. I have also tried to add some left constrain without right. I'm aware that on the right side page control will be still out of screen.

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26833487/3985749) - scale it down in size so all the dots are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling is an option if number of pages is constant or at least it has similar value. However, I ended up with manually adjusting the page control frame if it's width is greater than screen bounds.